# Why doesn't MDF.extract_bus_loging() function extract all of my CAN signals?

Tags: python, pandas, asammdf

I am using the asammdf library for extracting CAN messages from MF4 files.
the function `extract_bus_logging` called on a `mdf` object is supposed to extract all possible CAN messages using given CAN database.
In my database I have multiple CAN messages containing different signals. Say, I have a message "A" containing signals "1, 2, 3" and message "B" containing signals "4, 5, 6".
When I call the `extract_bus_logging` function, it extracts signals from only one CAN message - I would end up only with signals "1, 2, 3".
How do I extract all the signals from all the can messages?

Here is my python sample code:

```
def convert_mf4(mf4_file: os.path, dbc_set: set) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Converts and decodes MF4 files to a dataframe using DBC files."""
    # convert MF4 to MDF
    mdf = MDF(mf4_file)
    # extract CAN messages
    extracted_mdf = mdf.extract_bus_logging(database_files=dbc_set)
    # return MDF converted to dataframe
    mdf_df = extracted_mdf.to_dataframe(time_from_zero=False, time_as_date=True)
    mdf_df.index = pd.to_datetime(mdf_df.index)
    return mdf_df
```

`dbc_set` is a structure of can database files, as required in the MDF [documentation](https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asammdf.mdf.MDF.extract_bus_logging).

I have tried different CAN databases, but the problem was always the same. Only the first message gets extracted.